# I cannot find my previous applications and I cannot make a new one

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

I received an upgrade notification and afterward I cannot find my running application nor can I start a new one (this account cannot start more than 1 project). How can I find my old project?

[image]

This is what my console looks like (https://console.starter-us-west-2.openshift.com/console/), I can't find the entry to my previous project.

When I try to create a new project, I see this:

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the shutdown of OpenShift 2? That was some time ago. What URLs are you using to access the OpenShift instance you are talking about?

Comment: No i am using the openshift 3 starter. I uses sth like us west 2 dot console i will make a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenShift Online Starter tier is intended for experimentation and use in development and testing. It is not intended for permanent production applications. As described in Frequently Asked Questions at:

- https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html

applications can be subject to removal if you do not use the platform for an extended period.

> WHAT HAPPENS WHEN MY ONLINE STARTER ACCOUNT IS INACTIVE? We
>   periodically remove inactive users from OpenShift Online Starter to
>   free up resources for new users. If your account is removed, you can
>   resubscribe at any time.
>
> OpenShift Online Starter is intended for learning and experimenting,
>   not for hosting projects. Accordingly, we consider "activity" to mean
>   that you are using your account to build and deploy applications.
>
> If you are using OpenShift Online Starter infrequently, we recommend
>   that you backup your applications and data. See "Creating a Template
>   from Existing Objects" to backup your applications and "Backing up and
>   Restoring Databases" to backup your databases.

So if you got an email, it may well have been warning you about this.

If this is what happened, you can reactivate your account again and starting using the platform again.

Whether you needed to reactivate your account or not, you only get one project. You can see what projects you have from the web console, or from the command line by running `oc projects`.

If you have no projects and trying to create one fails, then it may be because that project name is already in use by a different user. Try a different project name.

Comment: Hey graham, I didn't receive any emails, and I am not sure how to see if my account is active. It looks active to me. It just doesn't let me create a new project. Please see my updated question with screenshots.

Comment: What do you get when you log in from the command line and run ``oc get projects``? One possibility is that when/if your project was deleted, it hasn't been cleaned up properly resulting in you being unable to create a new one, If that is the case, you will need to raise an issue with the OpenShift Online Support team. Link somewhere under the Help pages.